# c++ std::vector of functions passed as a parameter of a class method

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, stdvector

(1) How do you create an std::vector of functions so that you could do something like this:

```
int main ()
{
    std::vector<????> vector_of_functions;
    // Add an adding function into the vector
    vector_of_functions.push_back(
        double function (double a, double b) {
            return a + b
        }
    );
    // Add a multiplying function into the vector
    vector_of_functions.push_back(
        double function (double a, double b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    );

    //  Use the functions
    std::cout << "5 + 7 = " << vector_of_functions[0](5, 7); // >>> 5 + 7 = 12
    std::cout << "5 * 7 = " << vector_of_functions[1](5, 7); // >>> 5 * 7 = 35

    return 0;
}
```

While I would like if the function return and parameters could be any type, it doesn't have to be.  I'm fine if they're a set type.

(2) How do you pass that kind of std::vector as a parameter of a function.

```
void func (std::vector<???> vof) {
    std::cout << vof[0](5, 7);
};
int main ()
{
    std::vector<????> vector_of_functions;
    // Add an adding function into the vector
    vector_of_functions.push_back(
        double function (double a, double b) {
            return a + b
        }
    );
    // Add a multiplying function into the vector
    vector_of_functions.push_back(
        double function (double a, double b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    );

    //  Call the function
    func( vector_of_functions ); // >>> 12

    return 0;
}
```

(3) How do I do the same thing except where the function is a method of a class defined in a header file.
The .cpp code will be the same as before, except the function will be `void ClassName::func(...);`
The .h code will be something like this:

```
class ClassName {
    public:
        ClassName();
        void func(????);
}
```

Comment: have a look at `std::function` and `std::bind`

Comment: Use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), Luke!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++11+, than you can use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), or [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

So, something like:

```
using func = std::function<double(double, double)>;
using vfuncs = std::vector<func>;

vfuncs vf;
vf.push_back([](double first, double second) { return first + second; });
vf.push_back([](double first, double second) { return first * second; });
/* obj is some function, which member function you want to call */
vf.push_back([&obj](double first, double second) { return obj.op(first, second); });
```

Comment: This is better than my answer and should be accepted.

Comment: Thanks.  This works when I change `using vfuncs = std::vector<func>;` to `std::vector<func> vfuncs;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::function<double(double,double)>` as the template parameter for your vector and then use either `std::function<double(double,double)>` objects or something that can convert to `std::function<double(double,double)>`, such as a lamda: for example `[](double a, double b) -> double { return a + b; }`.